# Visual Studio Code Grammar files location

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Visual Studio Code for development of PHP and would like to style the background color of the different embedded languages HTML/PHP/JavaScript differently, and to trigger the use of heredoc `<<<sql .... sql` to switch to SQL syntax. From what I can see from VSCode documentation, I need to edit the grammar files stored in storage.json, but for the life of me I cannot find where those files are. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: try to go to ```./yourVSCodeFolder/extensions/resources/app/extensions```. There you will find a lot of folders that contains JSON files with the instructions of the custom formats and snippets that your editor uses.
for example: in mine, the ```/php/syntax/php.tmLanguage.json``` file has all the instructions for how my php should look, and the ```php/language-configuration.json``` has some parsing rules.
Find the files that allready has the rules that you are looking for, but it could be tricky because maybe you will need a prettyfier and to link or create new rules.
Hope it was useful.

Comment: Also, if you didn't, check the [Language Extensions Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) that VSCode provides.

Comment: Thanks @LautaroJayat, if you want to change your comment to an answer, I can mark it as accepted. For those on windows, that folder is %LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\php

Comment: I also found that VSCode already recognizes embedded SQL as long as the heredoc is in upper case `<<<SQL .... SQL`. I would rather change my code than change the VSCode configuration.

Comment: For me, the location is now: `./yourVSCodeFolder/resources/app/extensions/ `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sumirizing our comments, in order to modify the extension files, try to access the following folder:

```
./yourVSCodeFolder/extensions/resources/app/extensions
```

As you said, for those in windows, that folder is in:

> `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\php`

There you will find a lot of folders that contains JSON files with the instructions of the custom formats and snippets that your editor uses.

For example: in mine, the **`/syntax/php.tmLanguage.json`** has all the instructions for how my php should look, and **`php/language-configuration.json`** has some parsing rules.

Find the files that allready has the rules that you are looking for, but it could be tricky because maybe you will need a prettyfier and to link or create new rules.

Also, if you didn't, [check the Language Extensions Guide that VSCode provides](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide).

Hope it was useful.

PD: As you also said:

> VSCode already recognizes embedded SQL as long as the heredoc is in upper case `<<<SQL .... SQL`

Comment: For those on linux using snap, it can be found here: `/snap/code/current/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions`