# Paint unquoted JSON keys as valid tokens in VS Code

Tags: parsing, visual-studio-code

I am working with a group of JSON files from a developer who didn't like the idea of double quoting the keys as shown below:

```
{   
    ingredientPattern: "PPP,PSP,PRP",
    ingredients: {
        "S": { type: "item", code: "saw-*", isTool: true, toolDurabilityCost: 60 },
        "P": { type: "item", code: "plank-*", quantity: 6 },
        "R": { type: "block", code: "rock-*", name: "rock", allowedVariants: ["andesite", "granite", "basalt", "peridotite"]  }
    },
    width: 3,
    height: 3,
    output: { type: "block", code: "pulverizerframe-north", quantity: 1 }
}
```

As a result, every time I open one of these files in VS Code, I'm greeted with a sea of errors.

I managed to mitigate the errors red underlining by assigning an association `*.json --> jsonl`. But the dark theme stills painting the keys in red.

By enabling the option *Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes* and clicking in one of the red keys to see what's going on, I got the following result in the popup:

```
d1 char
language    jsonl
standard token type Other
foreground  #F44747
background  #1F1F1F
contrast ratio  4.58
textmate scopes invalid.illegal.expected-dictionary-separator.json.lines
meta.structure.dictionary.json.lines
meta.structure.array.json.lines
source.json.lines
foreground  invalid
{ "foreground": "#F44747" }
```

And the `foreground invalid` line makes it clear: the grammar parser is labeling the keys as invalid.

While I could change the theme color for invalid tokens, I'd prefer not to. Those red alerts are handy when dealing with potentially problematic syntax. Instead, I'd like to tweak the grammar parser logic. I want it to treat undoublequoted keys as `support.type.property-name`, just like it does with double-quoted keys.

After some research and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445205/visual-studio-code-grammar-files-location) I found the grammar file at `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\json\syntaxes\JSONL.tmLanguage.json` and the lines that seem to be selecting the JSONL key:

```
"objectkey": {
  "begin": "\"",
  "beginCaptures": {
    "0": {
      "name": "punctuation.support.type.property-name.begin.json.lines"
    }
  },
  "end": "\"",
  "endCaptures": {
    "0": {
      "name": "punctuation.support.type.property-name.end.json.lines"
    }
  },
  "name": "string.json.lines support.type.property-name.json.lines",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "include": "#stringcontent"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am not sure about what to put in the regex for the new captures or if I have to change other parts of the file in order to get it working properly.

Any advice on what to do?

Comment: It matters very little what your programmer likes or doesn't like.  They may be accepted by Javascript, but those files are not valid JSON.  If he is supposed to create JSON, then he has failed in his task.  End of story.

Comment: if the keys aren't quoted, that's... not JSON. it could be a JS object literal, but not JSON.

Comment: @TimRoberts Unfortunately I can't do anything about it. I am developing tools for a finished product which reads the files in this format. I also tried making the file association *.json --> javascript, but then the errors are triggered by the missing semicolon. We are talking about thousands of files in this format.

Comment: @starball I know... But I can't do much about it. I am just trying to setup the VS Code in such a way that allows me to look at the files without burning my eyes in hell fire red.

Comment: How much trouble do you want to go to?  If you have node.js installed, it would be easy to write a little node.js app to read that in and write it out in proper JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where I had to do more research before assuming the files format is wrong.

They are in JSON5 format defined at [json5.org](https://json5.org/), and its totally correct.

Installing the JSON5 extension did the trick: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-json5

Comment: gosh darn it. had to go afk and got ninja'd